# Non-STL Binary Search Tree Search Function Problem

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node(T key) :data(key), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    };

    Node * root;

    int size(Node * node);
    void printNode(Node*);
    void deleteNode(Node*);
    void insert(Node * node, Node * nodePtr);   
    void inorder(Node * root, void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const;
    void preorder(Node * root, void(*preorderPtr)(T &)) const;
    void postorder(Node * root, void(*postorderPtr)(T &)) const;

public:

    BinarySearchTree();
    ~BinarySearchTree();
    T search(T value);
    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<T> & source);
    const BinarySearchTree<T> & operator = (const Node & other);
    void insert(const T);
    void print();
    int size();
    void inorder(void(*output)(T &)) const;
    void preorder(void(*preorderPtr)(T &)) const;
    void postorder(void(*postorderPtr)(T &)) const;
};
```

```
template<class T>
inline T BinarySearchTree<T>::search(T value)
{
    if (value == this->root){
        return value;
    }
    else if (value < this->root)
    {
        if (left == nullptr){}  
        else
        {
            return left->search(value);
        }
    }
    else if (value > this->root)
    {
        if (right == nullptr){}
        else
        {
            return right->search(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T'(or there is no acceptable conversion)

Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Error   C2678   binary '>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

like this

```
bool handler::operator>(const weatherData & w)
{
    bool temp = false;

    if (w > this->testD)
    {
        temp = true;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

i am attempting to retrieve a map that is stored inside the BST, i have overload operator for that specific object but for some reason the code above throws these errors.do i need overload operators in my BST if it is type T? any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. where is `root` defined?

Comment: Also what type do you used as `T` in the example?

Comment: its of type object weatherData